# Dynamic SQL query to return results in columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I have this basic database table and am SQL beginner.

```
+-------------+--------+----------+
|  location   |  Week  | Expenses |
+-------------+--------+----------+
| Backoffice  | 201851 |       80 |
| frontoffice | 201852 |      110 |
| Backoffice  | 201901 |      120 |
| Backoffice  | 201902 |       70 |
| frontoffice | 201903 |       68 |
+-------------+--------+----------+
```

Is there a way to dynamically retrieve the last 5 weeks result, instead of hard coding it every time in my pivot table?

Here is my code:

```
  SELECT *  from
  (SELECT[week]
        ,[Expenses]
from [cafe].[dbo].[table]where location = 'Backoffice'
) as Total_Expenses pivot (sum([expenses]) for [week] in ([201902],[201903],[201904],[201905],[201906],[201907],[201908],[201909])) as pivotable;
```

I would like to be able to just enter "5" and it shows me the last 5 week. May be by a "max" formula"

Comment: what RDBMS system? SQL Server/MySQL/Oracle/etc?

Comment: SQL Server - Apologies, still learning the site rules

Comment: Yes, you're correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle a variable number of columns (weeks) you can use dynamic TSQL:

```
create  table #tmp(location varchar(50), Week varchar(6),Expenses int)
insert into #tmp values
('Backoffice' ,'201851', 80),('frontoffice','201852',110),('Backoffice' ,'201901',120),('Backoffice' ,'201902', 70),('frontoffice','201903', 68)

declare @startDate date = '20190131' --Start date, probably you'll want to put Getdate() here
declare @weeks     table ([weekNumber] nvarchar(4), [weekYear] nvarchar(4))
declare @weekCount int = 10        --numbers of weeks to show
declare @counter   int = 0         --counter to loop on all weeks
declare @weekList  varchar(max)='' --holds the list of dynamically generated column headers 
declare @sql       varchar(max)='' --holds the complete dynamical TSQL query

set @counter = @weekCount
while @counter > 0
begin
    insert into @weeks 
    SELECT right('0' + cast(DATEPART(wk, DATEADD(WK,-(@counter),@startDate)) as varchar(2)),2)
           , DATEPART(year, DATEADD(WK,-(@counter),@startDate))
    set @counter = @counter - 1
end

select @weekList = @weekList + '[' + [weekYear] + [weekNumber] + '],' from @weeks 

set @weekList = SUBSTRING(@weekList, 1, len(@weekList) - 1)

set @sql = @sql + '  SELECT *  from'
set @sql = @sql + '  (SELECT[week]'
set @sql = @sql + '        ,[Expenses]'
set @sql = @sql + ' from #tmp where location = ''Backoffice'''
set @sql = @sql + ' ) as Total_Expenses pivot (sum([expenses]) for [week] in ('+@weekList+')) as pivotable;'

--execute dynamic query
exec(@sql)
```

Output with `@weekCount = 5`:

[image]

Output with `@weekCount = 10`:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to select top 5 weeks (most recent weeks) use `TOP`: [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM [cafe].[dbo].[table]
WHERE location = 'Backoffice'
ORDER BY Week Desc
```

Change the last line to `ORDER BY Week [ ASC | DESC ]` to change the order.

---

If you want get top 5 weeks, and sum the expense by week (I assume you want to group by week and location) then try this:

```
select top (5) Location, Week, sum(Expenses)
FROM table_name
WHERE location = 'backoffice'
GROUP BY Week, Location
Order By Week Desc
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/57fd0/8)

*P.S. I would recommend not using [table], as your table name*.

Comment: My data has multiple lines with same week#, will this sum them? the result i'm after is like this heading:      Location | 201915 | 201914 | 201913 | 201912

Comment: Nope, do you want to sum them?

Comment: Yes please, the data above is just a sample, I have lots and lots of rows

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a pivot.  I would suggest conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN weeknum = 1 THEN expenses END) as week_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN weeknum = 2 THEN expenses END) as week_2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN weeknum = 3 THEN expenses END) as week_3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN weeknum = 4 THEN expenses END) as week_4,
       SUM(CASE WHEN weeknum = 5 THEN expenses END) as week_5       
FROM (SELECT t.*,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY WEEK DESC) as weeknum
      FROM [cafe].[dbo].[table] t
     ) t 
WHERE location = 'Backoffice';
```

Note that this pivots the values but gives them generic names.  If you actually want to change the names of the columns you need dynamic SQL.

Comment: This is somewhat similar to what  I had prior to moving into pivot. The issue is I may require last 5 weeks or it could be even last 20 weeks